# Euler's/Carmichael's theorems generalisation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)
 states that

> if $n$ is a prime number then $a^n \equiv a \pmod n$.

[Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) and [Carmichael's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) relax it from "if $n$ is a prime number" to

> if $a$ and $n$ are coprime integers then $a^m \equiv a \pmod n$.

, where $m=\phi(n)+1$ for Euler's theorem and $m=\lambda(n)+1$ for Carmichael's theorem.

That theorems are pretty amazing and simplify modular calculations a lot.

But what if $a$ and $n$ aren't coprimes? Are there some generalisations to previous theorems for arbitrary $a$ and $n$, or for $a$ and $n$ with even more relaxed requirements?

Comment: That should be $m = \phi(n)+1$ and $\lambda(n)+1$.

Answer (score 2):

If, for example, prime $p$ divides both $a$ and $n$ but $p^2$ divides $n$ and does not divide $a$, then $a^m \not\equiv a\; (\text{mod}\; n)$ for any $m > 1$.

On the other hand, if $n$ is squarefree then for any $a$, $a^{\lambda(n)+1} \equiv a \; (\text{mod}\; n)$.